# How to use booleans return from SELECT IF in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a query that I'd like to run which isn't really complicated but MySQL doesn't want to make my life easy and keeps giving `error 1064`. Here is the overall structure of the query:

```
IF EXISTS(query) AND IF NOT EXISTS(query)
BEGIN
    INSERT ...
    DELETE ...
END
```

Now I have used this overall structure but I don't think MySQL supports this because I get `error 1064`. So instead I have been using the following query:

```
SELECT IF(
    EXISTS(query) AND NOT EXISTS(query), 1, 0
);
```

This works well and returns the proper bool value.

**My question is** how can I now use this bool value returned and do the `insert` and `delete` operations I have in the overall structure which I gave above? Perhaps there's even a better way I have yet to come across to get this work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's `IF` syntax requires a `THEN` and `END IF`. You don't have either. You need to study the syntax reference and examples carefully: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/if.html

Also, MySQL doesn't currently allow `IF/THEN/END IF` outside of stored routines. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-compound-statements.html says:

> This section describes the syntax for the BEGIN ... END compound statement and other statements that can be used in the body of stored programs: Stored procedures and functions, triggers, and events.

If you want conditional logic, you're expected to write code in a client application.

Comment: Yes I have already implemented this logic in my backend however it currently requires 4 separate queries. So I was trying to find a way to do this more efficiently in one go and have been stuck trying to get the conditionals to work. I'll take a look at routines next though. Thank you.

Comment: I really don't recommend using stored routines in MySQL. They're difficult to develop and deploy, they don't compile, documentation is scarce, etc. I would stick with writing code in the application layer.